# XMobar disappears behind background when restarting XMonad in Gnome session

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I use a layout with avoidStruts so that I can bind key
((myModMask, xK_b), sendMessage ToggleStruts)
to hide the xmobar toolbar.

Now I have a strange behaviour:
When restarting XMonad with "mod-q", XMobar in a GNOME
session gets hidden behind the background window
and doesnt come up again. ToggleStruts still seems to
works though, only that only the background is visible where
the XMobar should be.

Here are my config files:

https://github.com/eiselekd/dotfiles/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

Is there any easy workaround? Maybe send the background window behind the XMobar again...

I know that there are the XMobar options

```
overrideRedirect = False
lowerOnStart = False
```

however whilst XMobar is visible on startup when these 
options are added, the XMobar window is suddenly not hidden by ToggleStruts
any more. So I dont want to use these.

Another possibility that I tried and that is working is to spawn in the StartupHook

```
xdotool windowraise `xdotool search --all --name xmobar`
```

to raise XMobar via xdotool, however I would like to know a 
XMonad/Haskell command instead.

Comment: What version of Xmonad are you using?

Comment: I was using XMonad 0.12 from Ubuntu 16.04. I was creating a gnome session setup to be able to show the gnome-panel because I wanted the network manager toolbar icon. The "xdotool" solution worked ok, so I leave it as "solved". Lately I changed to just running xmonad with no gnome session below, so there I dont have the issue.